# Create a fully dynamic table in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have defined a `model` in EmberJS with the following attributes:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    "name": DS.attr('string'),
    "status": DS.attr('string'),
    "email1": DS.attr('string'),
    "account_name": DS.attr('string'),
    "phone_work": DS.attr('string'),
    "date_entered": DS.attr('string'),
    "date_modified": DS.attr('string')
});
```

I am creating a `component` called `fields-list` that would render these attributes into a table (headers, body; just like a typical table to list some fields). However, instead of making the table bound to this `model` only, I want to make the `component` fully dynamic, so that other models with different field names could also reuse this `component` to generate their tables as well.

This way, whenever the `component` is used, it detects the `model` and populates the headers of the table as well as the body according to the fields in that `model`.

How do I achieve this? If there is anything that's not clear in the query please do let me know, I've tried my best to explain the issue properly as much as I can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you had a look on existing table implementations? There are a lot ember addons trying to achieve exactly what you want: https://www.emberobserver.com/categories/lists-and-tables

Comment: what have you tried so far and what is your problem? Have a look at [eachAttribute](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Model/methods/eachAttribute?anchor=eachAttribute).

Comment: I have looked at [ember contextual table](https://github.com/tubitak-bilgem-yte/ember-contextual-table#readme) and [ember light table](http://offirgolan.github.io/ember-light-table/docs/) . **Ember Light Table** has better documentation but I do not understand how to add table headers and data from the `model` dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't personally use Ember Data, so there might be better ways to do what you're doing, but I got a solution for you available as an [ember twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/28586b27cbbe6689a07406df396c9821?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.components.dynamic-table.hbs) or as a [gist](https://gist.github.com/henryw14/28586b27cbbe6689a07406df396c9821). This is nothing more than a proof of concept.

Let's break the question down really fast. You want to create a component that can take any model and magically build a table for you. At the highest level, we know that we need to be able to iterate over the data model's definition and create columns of specific types based off of the Ember Data types you've passed as `DS.attr`. Thinking further, we know Ember Data must have some sort of ability to do the same: [eachAttribute](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/3.5/classes/DS.Model/methods/eachAttribute?anchor=eachAttribute). If it's a private API, recognize this is brittle and version specific (aka write tests).

So, given a model Foo:

```
import Model from 'ember-data/model';
import attr from 'ember-data/attr';

export default Model.extend({
    "name": attr('string'),
    "status": attr('string')
});
```

Let's get the model's definition via the constructor:

```
var record = this.store.createRecord('foo', {
    name: "model1",
    status: "status1"
});
this.modelClass = record.constructor;
```

Ember light table takes a columns definition object which we can create dynamically from within our component through the use of `eachAttribute` on said model class:

```
columns: computed('modelClass', function() {
    let modelClass = this.modelClass;
    if(!modelClass){ return [] }
    let columns = [];
    modelClass.eachAttribute(function(key, meta){ 
      columns.push({
         label: key,
         valuePath: key
      });
    });
    return columns;
})
```

it's here that you could inspect the `meta` parameter of the `eachAttribute` function for the specific type of each attribute to set the `cellComponent` property within the column definition should you want to render different cell types.

There's a project called [Ember Admin](https://github.com/DockYard/ember-admin) that builds up a CRUD interface automagically off of your data model so there's a place of inspiration.

Comment: Thanks! the explanation and twiddle really helped with understanding the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Why resort to addons if you can just build this yourself?

`app/templates/some-route.hbs`

```
<FieldsList
  @resources={{users}}
  @columns='id, firstName, lastName, job.title, job.company.name'
  @sortBy='firstNameAsc'
  @filterBy='firstName, lastName'
/>
```

`app/components/fields-list/component.js`

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  classNames: ['fields-list'],

  // Splits the string of keys into an array
  columnMap: computed(function() {
    return this.columns.replace(/ /g, '').split(/,/g);
  })
});
```

`app/components/fields-list/template.hbs`

```
<ul>
  {{#each resources as |resource|}}
    <li>
      {{#each columnMap as |column|}}
        <span>{{get resource key}}</span>
      {{/each}}
    </li>
  {{else}}
    <li>No humans found</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`app/components/fields-list/style.scss`

```
.fields-list {
  li {
    display: flex;
    span {
      flex: 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Done in ember-cli: 3.5.0

Comment: Interesting solution, although I think you may have swapped the second and third paths by accident. Nevertheless I understand where you're going with this. Thanks :)